# Problems printing the content of the kafka streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to implement a Kafka consumer in Java, in order to receive and process records from the Kafka topics. First of all I would like to start by printing the content of the stream on standard output.

My problem is that the content of the stream is always empty, even though the length of the data is never zero.

This is my code:

```
public class PrintData {

      private static Consumer<Long, String> createConsumer() {
          final Properties props = new Properties();
          props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka:9092");
          props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "KafkaExampleConsumer");
          props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class.getName());
          props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());


          // Create the consumer using props.
          final Consumer<Long, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

          // Subscribe to the topic.
          consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("print_label"));
          return consumer;
      }

    static void runConsumer() throws InterruptedException {
        final Consumer<Long, String> consumer = createConsumer();

        final int giveUp = 100;   int noRecordsCount = 0;

        while (true) {
            final ConsumerRecords<Long, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

            if (consumerRecords.count()==0) {
                noRecordsCount++;
                if (noRecordsCount > giveUp) break;
                else continue;
            }

            consumerRecords.forEach(record -> {
                System.out.println(record.toString());              
                System.out.println("Record value: " + record.value());
                System.out.println("Value length: " + record.value().length());
                System.out.println("");

            });

            consumer.commitAsync();
        }
        consumer.close();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }


    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        runConsumer();
    }
}
```

And this is my output when I inject data in Kafka:

```
ConsumerRecord(topic = print_label, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 41, CreateTime = 1551367936305, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 144, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = 
Record value:
Value length: 141
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Are you sure that value of message is simple `String`, not some POJO serialized with more complex `Serializer`?

Comment: I'm injecting a JSON string with an Avro Producer @wardziniak